# Why this C++ program results wrong outputs for some unknown testcases, I'm unable to debug?

Tags: c++

I'm getting correct result for my inputs(I have tried 30+ inputs manually and got correct output for all), but after submitting on a practice portal, some testcases are resulting wrong output and I'm unable to debug!

**Question for reference**: Chef likes to play with cards a lot. Today, he's playing a game with three cards. Each card has a letter written on the top face and another (possibly identical) letter written on the bottom face. Chef can arbitrarily reorder the cards and/or flip any of the cards in any way he wishes (in particular, he can leave the cards as they were). He wants to do it in such a way that the letters on the top faces of the cards, read left to right, would spell out the name of his favorite friend Bob.
Determine whether it is possible for Chef to spell "bob" with these cards.

*My approach: I think the correct output can be achieved if:*

- Two 'b' & 'o' is in first string or in second string.
- if Two 'b' and 'o' is
  not found in first and second string directly then two 'b' & 'o' have to
  exist on individual cards so that we can rearrange or flip accordingly.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstring>

  int main()
   {
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;

    while (t--)
    {
   std::string s1, s2, s;
   std::cin >> s1 >> s2;

   /* In String1 indiviually */
   int index1 = s1.find('b', 0);
   int index2 = s1.find('b', index1 + 1);
   int index3 = s1.find('o', 0);

   if (index1 != -1 && index2 != -1 && index3 != -1)
   {
       std::cout << "yes" << '\n';
       continue;
   }

   /* In String2 indiviually */
   int pos1 = s2.find('b', 0);
   int pos2 = s2.find('b', pos1 + 1);
   int pos3 = s2.find('o', 0);

   if (pos1 != -1 && pos2 != -1 && pos3 != -1)
   {
       std::cout << "yes" << '\n';
       continue;
   }

   /* Now checking whole string1 and string2 or on the top of card as well as foot of card */
   s = s1 + s2;
   int count = s.length();
   int sum = 0;

   int key1 = s.find('b', 0);
   if (key1 != -1)
   {
       sum++;
       int xflag1 = key1 + 3; /* if found on top then change its footer to 'z' and vice- 
                                 versa.
                                 this is because lets assume if I found 'b' on top of a card 
                                 and also there exist 'b' or 'o'
                                 on its footer then its create wrong output for next 
                                 std::string.find() */
       int xflag2 = key1 - 3;

       if (xflag1 < count)
       {
           s[xflag1] = 'z';
       }

       if (xflag2 >= 0)
       {
           s[xflag2] = 'z';
       }
   }

   int key2 = s.find('b', key1 + 1);
   if (key2 != -1)
   {
       sum++;
       int xflag1 = key2 + 3;
       int xflag2 = key2 - 3;

       if (xflag1 < count)
       {
           s[xflag1] = 'z';
       }

       if (xflag2 >= 0)
       {
           s[xflag2] = 'z';
       }
   }

   int key3 = s.find('o', 0);
   if (key3 != -1)
   {
       sum++;
       int xflag1 = key3 + 3;
       int xflag2 = key3 - 3;

       if (xflag1 < count)
       {
           s[xflag1] = 'z';
       }

       if (xflag2 >= 0)
       {
           s[xflag2] = 'z';
       }
   }

   if (sum == 3)
   {
       std::cout << "yes" << '\n';
   }
   else
       std::cout << "no" << '\n';
   }

  return (0);
  }
  ```

Comment: The nice thing about "the real world" is that sooner or later one can usually coax the input needed to replicate the problem out of the users. On online judge or competition sites it's not that easy. Which is yet another reason they're not very good for teaching or learning.

Comment: `bbboxx` would fail

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because technically ot does not provide a minimal complete example, and generally it is of little use to future visitors.

Comment: Okay, I agree to it, actually @appleapple points my error and I'm glad to found that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bbboxx` would fail since you first filter out card with `b`

---

You can try separate cards into categories

1. card with `o` and `b`
2. card with only `o`
3. card with only `b`
4. card with neither (no use)

then compute the result